# Elastic Search Document Boosting (like Solr elevateIds)

Tags: elasticsearch

Looking to move from Solr to Elastic Search due to its amazon REST API and suitability for clustering. However I am struggling to figure out a way to boost at query time specific documents like in Solrs elevate method. Is there a way to do this and if so any examples would be really helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're referencing the Solr QueryElevationComponent. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

There has been previous discussion on github as to how to emulate this functionality in Elasticsearch. https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1066

The idea is to use the Elasticsearch Constant Score Query to apply a constant boost for matching documents. Apply a big enough boost and you in effect get the "sponsored search" result of Solr's Elevate.

From the documentation:

> **Constant Score Query**
>
> A query that wraps a filter or another query and simply returns a
>   constant score equal to the query boost for every document in the
>   filter. Maps to Lucene ConstantScoreQuery.
>
> ```
> {
>     "constant_score" : {
>         "filter" : {
>             "term" : { "user" : "kimchy"}
>         },
>         "boost" : 1.2
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The filter object can hold only filter elements, not queries. Filters
>   can be much faster compared to queries since they don’t perform any
>   scoring, especially when they are cached.
>
> A query can also be wrapped in a constant_score query:
>
> ```
> {
>     "constant_score" : {
>         "query" : {
>             "term" : { "user" : "kimchy"}
>         },
>         "boost" : 1.2
>     }
> }
> ```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

**EDIT**

Example using multiple boosts:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                            "user": ["kimchy", "john"]
                        }
                    },
                    boost: 3
                }
            }, {
                "constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                            "user": ["paul", "ringo"]
                        }
                    },
                    boost: 2
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi John, would this work for ordering records in a required order, like Solrs query elevation?

Comment: If you are ordering by score, you boost the documents by a sufficient margin so that they always appear at the top of the sorted list.

Comment: We are wanting to control the order of the elevated/sponsored records. We don't just want them to appear at the top in any order.

Comment: so give each document a different boost, higher boost to the document you want first, etc.

Comment: Could you possibly edit your answer to show the JSON structure for multiple different boosts?